# How can I transform Unit object to DTO object?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to change my code to strategy pattern using spring boot and kotlin, but I can not return my object list in function into Service. How can i transform the output of my forEach which is a Unit to an list of Object DTO which is what my function should actually return? Below are the codes:

```
interface RecommendationStrategy {

    fun validateCorrect(amount: BigDecimal, asset: Asset?, reasonId: Int?): Boolean

    fun send(): List<ProductDto>
}

@Component
class StrategyA(
    private val serviceHelper: ServiceHelper
) : RecommendationStrategy {
    override fun validateCorrect(amount: BigDecimal, asset: Asset?, reasonId: Int?): Boolean {
        if (/* logical conditions */) {
            return true
        }
        if (/* logical conditions */) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun send(): List<ProductDto> {
        return serviceHelper.getProducts().filter { it.id!! == 3L || it.id == 1L }
            .map { serviceHelper.getlProductMap(it) }.sortedByDescending { it.id }
    }
}

@Component
class StrategyB(
    private val serviceHelper: ServiceHelper
) : RecommendationStrategy {

    override fun validateCorrect(amount: BigDecimal, asset: Asset?, reasonId: Int?): Boolean {
        if (/* logical conditions */)) {
            return true
        }
        if (/* logical conditions */) {
            return true
        }
        if (/* logical conditions */) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun sendLoan(): List<ProductDto> {
        return serviceHelper.getProducts().filter { it.id!! == 1L }
            .map { serviceHelper.getProductMap(it) }
    }
}

@Service
class RecommendationService(
    private val recommendationStrategy: List<RecommendationStrategy>,
    private val serviceHelper: ServiceHelper
) {
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    fun getProductsRecommended(amount: BigDecimal, asset: Asset?, reasonId: Int?): List<ProductDto> {
        val result =
           recommendationStrategy.forEach { if (it.validateCorrectLoan(amount, asset, reasonId)) it.send() }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing _forEach_ with _map_. And obviously you then also need to return _result_.

Comment: When I try change forEach to map, I keep the same problem, I can't transform Unit to objectDTO. how would it be?

Comment: You want to return _List<FinancialProductDto>_ but _sendLoan()_ returns _List<ProductDto>_. And you are in a _map_, so the code assigned to _val result = ..._ is most probably a _List<List<ProductDto>>_. By the way: forEach does not return anything. _Unit_ basically stands for Nothing (or void, null, etc. in other programming languages).

Comment: i don't know how i edit my topic but i want to return a List<ProductDto> in getProductsRecommended. When I change to map I get the information:
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: 
required:
List<ProductDto>
found:
List<Unit>

Comment: And my function send return a List<ProductDto>, but i can't return it in map =/

Comment: A _map_ returns a List. But you return a List of Lists in your _map_. Maybe try with _flatMap_?

Comment: Maybe: _return recommendationStrategy.flatMap { if (it.validateCorrectLoan(amount, asset, reasonId)) it.send() }_

Comment: but my function send return a list of ProductDto and my function getProductsRecommended also. Where I am returning List of list? In getProductsRecommended i need return a List<ProductDto> because my controller return a List<ProductDto> on response.
When I use flatmap receive an error:
Type mismatch.
Required:
(RecommendationStrategy) → Iterable<???>
Found:
(RecommendationStrategy) → Unit

Comment: _recommendationStrategy_ is a list. If you do recommendationStrategy.map { ... } a List is returned. Since _send()_ returns a List, you now have a List of Lists. And with list.flatMap { ... } instead of list.map { ... } you get a List of all elements of all lists instead of a List of lists.

Comment: You also need an _else_ case. So return an empty list with _emptyList()_ for when _validateCorrect_ returns false: _return recommendationStrategy.flatMap { if (it.validateCorrect(amount, asset, reasonId)) it.send() else listOf() }_

Comment: Now I understand, but what would I need to change in my condition for a flatMap to work? Because he complains that my list is not iterable